# How to add two arrays together AND run methods on them to order, limit, or paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to make a news feed for a site and Im adding two arrays of different classes together to create a @feed_items array. But clearly I need to be able to order the new array by created_by

right now I have:

```
  def home
        @comments = Comment.all
        @images = Image.all
        @feed_items = @comments+@images
  end
```

So right now when I loop the @feed_items in my view, the loop displays all the comments (ordered by created_at), and then it display the images(ordered by created_at). But I need to order the entire array so everything is mixed up and ordered correctly.

I tried to do this:

```
  def home
        @comments = Comment.all
        @images = Image.all
        @feed_items = (@comments+@images).order('created_by DESC')
  end
```

But I get an undefined method error for the @feed_items array. Same thing with tying to use limit or paginate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't do it in SQL, which is the case when you're dealing with two different tables in a single query, you can do it with Ruby:

```
def home
 @comments = Comment.all
 @images = Image.all

 @feed_items = (@comments + @images).sort_by(&:created_at)
end
```

Remember that using the `all` method can be dangerous because you may have, potentially, tens of thousands of records. It's always a good idea to use a pagination system like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) if nothing else.

Comment: awesome, man I love this site! I am using will_paginate for the site, but the paginate method doesnt work on that combined array.

Comment: will_paginate uses some sql statements to do the pagination, that's why it wont work on the combined array, and that's why I didn't mention it

Comment: What you should do is fetch a limited number of results, then merge them together. At least `Comment.limit(50).all` or some reasonable constraint. If you have 5,000,000 comments, which isn't improbable, your app will melt down.

Comment: The better solution is to have Comment and Image be the same type somehow, that way you can use SQL to do the limiting and sorting for you, keeping the work out of Rails

Comment: oh so theres no way to paginate a combined array?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000244) and [take](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000292)

```
def home
    @comments = Comment.all
    @images = Image.all
    @feed_items = (@comments+@images).sort{|x,y| y.created_by <=> x.created_by}
end

home.take(10)
```